# win32com python unusual behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, pywin32, win32com

New to win32com. Below is my code for converting xlsx file to webpage and capturing the range of cells as .png. The problem I am facing is that some times the code run fine but sometimes it throws errors.

```
import os
import sys
import win32com.client
from win32com.client.gencache import EnsureDispatch
from win32com.client import constants
from win32com.client import DispatchEx

import PIL
from PIL import ImageGrab


# #---------------------------standalone--------------------------------
path = r'path'
Temp='folder'
#
## ---------------------------------------------------------------------
filename1='Images.html'

images='Images_files'

def A(source):


    xl = EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(yourExcelFile)
    wb.SaveAs(newFileName, constants.xlHtml)
    xl.Workbooks.Close()
    xl.Quit()
    del xl



Allsheets=[]
def B():

    xlApp = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
    xlApp.Visible = True
    wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(path,Temp,source))

    for sh in wb.Sheets:
        Allsheets.append(sh.Name)

    num=1     
    array=["AC7:AF10", "AC28:AF31","AC49:AF52"]
    for sheet_4 in Allsheets[:4]:
        xlApp.Worksheets(sheet_4).Activate()
        win32c = win32com.client.constants
        ws = xlApp.ActiveSheet

        for i in range(len(array)):
            ws.Range(array[i]).CopyPicture(Format=win32c.xlBitmap) 
            img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
            img.save(os.path.join(path,Temp,images,'TextBox0'+ f"{num:02}"+'.png'))
            num=num+1



    n=13 
    arry=["K5:M5","X5:Z5","K26:M26","X26:Z26","K47:M47","X47:Z47"]    
    for sheet_name in Allsheets[5:]:

        xlApp.Worksheets(sheet_name).Activate()
        win32c = win32com.client.constants
        ws = xlApp.ActiveSheet

        for i in range(len(arry)):
            ws.Range(arry[i]).CopyPicture(Format=win32c.xlBitmap) 
            img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
            img.save(os.path.join(path,Temp,images,'Avg0'+ f"{n:02}"+'.png'))
            n=n+1


    wb.Close(True)
    xlApp.Quit()

for f in os.listdir(os.path.join(path,Temp)):
    if f.endswith('.xlsx'):
        source=f

yourExcelFile = os.path.join(path,Temp,source)
newFileName = os.path.join(path,Temp,filename1)


A(source)
B()
```

The above code works fine for most of the times but throws the below error for the same input data it was working before. I have tried deleting gen_py and rerunning the code. Have referred almost all the solutions but nothing is clear and working as of now. Please someone suggest a solution.

```
    img.save(os.path.join(path,Temp,images,'TextBox0'+ f"{num:02}"+'.png'))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Comment: The error means that `ImageGrab.grabclipboard()` returned `None`, i. e. the clipboard didn't contain an image.

Comment: @MaxiMouse but how come how sometimes its returning image and sometimes not.

Comment: IS your test file always the same?

Comment: @tst Yes its the same.

Comment: @MaxiMouse @tst  below is the other error which throws sometimes for the same input data.`com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'CopyPicture method of Range class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HAHAHA.....,I used to meet this same problem when I use `PIL` module.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'
```

I guess that if you debug this code it could run this code normally,right?

There are two way to handle this:

```
import time

    time.sleep(1) # sleep for a while 
    img.save(os.path.join(path,Temp,images,'TextBox0'+ f"{num:02}"+'.png'))
```

Or (I recommend this):

```
while True:
    try:
        img.save(os.path.join(path,Temp,images,'TextBox0'+ f"{num:02}"+'.png'))
        break
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.args)
```

Comment: sleep worked for me. While loop is halting the execution and not proceeding nor stopping the execution.

Comment: @PythonBang Have you used ``break`` to exit this loop?

Comment: No not for loop . as you have suggested used break for try.

`for i in range(len(arry)):
            ws.Range(arry[i]).CopyPicture(Format=win32c.xlBitmap) 
            img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
            while True:
                try:
                    img.save(os.path.join(path,Temp,images,'TextBox0'+ f"{num:02}"+'.png'))
                    break
                except AttributeError:
                    pass
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e.args)
            n=n+1`

Comment: @PythonBang You have two places that ``img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()``.Do two places use while loop and break?

Comment: @jizihihaoSAMA yes it does